# SpringBoot API mapping working fine in local but not for Docker port

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, docker-compose

I'm not able to connect to spring boot API when using container port (8080) but is working fine when connected to local port (8080). I get Whitelabel Error Page for docker (http://localhost:9090/api/categories) and proper response for local port (http://localhost:8080/api/categories).
In container logs, I see following -

> No mapping for GET /api/categories

Following is my dockerfile -

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/spring-boot-ecommerce.jar spring-boot-ecommerce.jar
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spring-boot-ecommerce.jar"]
```

I have following in docker-compose -

```
ports:
  - '9090:8080'
```

Controller -

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/api/categories")
public class CategoryController{
  ...
}
```

[UPDATE] - In local, I'm hitting API like shown below -
[image]

For Docker port -
[image]

Controller method is like this -

```
@GetMapping()
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCategories() {
 ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the link, but I'm not getting CORS error, for me its mapping issue.

Comment: Well, this is weird. Could you please clarify what exactly is working fine? How do you run the app in that «fine» scenario?

Comment: I see your update. What is «in local»? How exactly do you deploy it locally? @coder87

Comment: Just for test only, do not use docker compose, just use `docker run -p 9000:8080 spring-boot-ecommerce`
then open another terminal run `curl http://localhost:9000/api/categories`.

Comment: I've jar file of spring boot in target folder and I start the application using embedded tomcat server of spring boot in Intellij by running main class.

Comment: There must be a difference in command line arguments if you compare starting the app using embedded tomcat and your docker entry point.